# Does the Sunburst spell blind constructs?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, constructs, blind

Does the *sunburst* spell blind constructs?

*Sunburst* is a 8th-level evocation with reflex save.

As I can read from the construct type entry on the SRD, they are not immune to blindness (except from necromancy spells). Also, saving throw is based on reflex and not fortitude.

I read (cannot remember the manual) that constructs have a magical sensor to see the surroundings. Is this magical sensor subject to blindness?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If constructs were generally immune to blindness, it would be in the Construct Type description as a trait. Construct traits list immunities to many things—but blindness isn’t one of them:

> - Immunity to all mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, phantasms, patterns, and morale effects).
> - Immunity to poison, sleep effects, paralysis, stunning, disease, death effects, and necromancy effects.
>
> […]
>
> - Not subject to critical hits, nonlethal damage, ability damage, ability drain, fatigue, exhaustion, or energy drain.
> - Immunity to any effect that requires a Fortitude save (unless the effect also works on objects, or is harmless).
> - Not at risk of death from massive damage. Immediately destroyed when reduced to 0 hit points or less.

Since blindness immunity is not mentioned in construct traits, constructs are not immune to blindness *in general*. (We also have traits relating to constructs’ vision, but those only note that they have low-light vision and 60-foot darkvision.)

Individual types of constructs may be immune to blindness—for that, you would have to check their monster entries. None of the *Monster Manual* constructs are immune to blindness, since none of them say they are, but, for example, high-level astral constructs from *Expanded Psionics Handbook* can have blindsight and thus be immune to blindness.

Finally, it’s possible for constructs—or other creatures—to be vulnerable to blindness, but still be immune to *sunburst* in particular. For instance, golems are infamously immune to spells that allow spell resistance, which *sunburst* does (“**SR:** Yes” in its description), so golems are immune to *sunburst* even though they may be blinded in other ways.